Strange olympiad question, real roots of a polynomial
My daughter took a recent math competition, and it had on it the following question, which I think is way too hard for an Olympiad for 7th and 8th graders. I don't really know how to do it. Can anyone shed some light?
Consider the equation:
$$
(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^3+1) = 30x^3
$$
Find the sum of all real roots of this equation.
My thinking is as follows. Expanding and moving to one side gives
$$
f(x):=x^6 + x^5 + x^4 -28x^3 +x^2 +x + 1 = 0.
$$
It's easy to see there can be no negative roots, since $x^6+x^5+x^4 > 0, x^2+x+1 > 0$ for all real $x$, and $-28x^3>0$ for negative $x$. It's also easy to see that there must be a least 2 positive roots, since $f(0) =1, f(1) < 0,$ and $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$. Descartes' rule of signs implies that these are the only 2 real roots. I note also that the symmetry of $f$ implies easily that if $w$ is a root then so is $1/w$. The product of the real roots is therefore $1$. We can also get the sum of all roots as the negative of the $x^5$ coefficient, so in this case $-1$. But I don't see how to find the roots easily. As it happens, wolframalpha gives the roots as $(3 \pm \sqrt{5})/2$, so they should sum to 3, but I don't see how to find that directly.
Greg

The polynomial $f(x)$ is palindromic of even degree. From the wikipedia article, it can be written in the form $f(x)= x^3 q(x+x^{-1})$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial )

It should help that $f(x) = (1 - 3 x + x^2) (1 + 4 x + 12 x^2 + 4 x^3 + x^4)$

Hint- Divide by $x^3$ and then take $x+(1/x)$ as t and then solve the cubic equation in t, it has known rational roots.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You answer is correct. I suggest that you should elaborate a little more. Otherwise, instead of having upvotes, you may get downvotes.

Cute trick, thanks! I see it now, but golly was that a hard question for 8th graders.
